# Ubuntu 18 some kinetic packages not found in melodic

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to install a number of packages which were present in `kinetic`:

```
$ apt-get install ros-melodic-joy ros-melodic-teleop-twist-joy ros-melodic-teleop-twist-keyboard ros-melodic-laser-proc ros-melodic-rgbd-launch ros-melodic-depthimage-to-laserscan ros-melodic-rosserial-arduino ros-melodic-rosserial-python ros-melodic-rosserial-server ros-melodic-rosserial-client ros-melodic-rosserial-msgs ros-melodic-amcl ros-melodic-map-server ros-melodic-move-base ros-melodic-urdf ros-melodic-xacro ros-melodic-compressed-image-transport ros-melodic-rqt-image-view ros-melodic-gmapping ros-melodic-navigation ros-melodic-interactive-markers
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-teleop-twist-joy
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-depthimage-to-laserscan
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-rosserial-arduino
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-rosserial-python
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-rosserial-server
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-rosserial-client
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-rosserial-msgs
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-gmapping
```

But as seen, some of their `melodic` counterparts can not be found. If these are available anyway, then where can I find the new packages names? I did `apt update` as suggested [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/204059/depthimage_to_laserscan-package-with-indigo/).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303253/ubuntu-18-some-kinetic-packages-not-found-in-melodic/) by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2018-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those packages appear to not have been released yet into Melodic.

You can use [status_page/compare_kinetic_melodic.html](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/compare_kinetic_melodic.html) to check.

For `teleop_twist_joy` for instance: [status_page/compare_kinetic_melodic.html?q=teleop_twist](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/compare_kinetic_melodic.html?q=teleop_twist):

[image: image description]

Notice how there is no version number in the `Melodic` column.

You can also check the wiki page of each package. Again for [teleop_twist_joy](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy):

[image: image description]

Notice how there is no version button for `melodic`.

---

Edit: if you still wish to use those packages, you could attempt a source build. That is more involved then installing using `apt-get` though.

See #q252478 for an *example* workflow.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some simple packages, you can just download the missing ones as source to your catkin_workspace and compile them. Larger packages with a lot of depencies get hard and will not work this way wihtout a lot of extra work.

---

Originally posted by [Boregard](https://answers.ros.org/users/33549/boregard/) with karma: 46 on 2018-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1